# How to wait for tasks to finish without blocking the UI

Tags: .net, vb.net, task

this is my first question in this forum and since I'm not a native english speaker I hope you'll go easy on me, in case I'm doing or saying something wrong.

So, here is my question:

I like to solve a simple problem (so it seems), but I'm already researching for over a week and tried different things but none of it worked so far, I always stumbled over the same problem.

What I like to do is opening a progress form, then starting two long running tasks (for instance getting data from two databases). These long running tasks report their progress to the progress form, after they're finished the progress form closes and another form opens to show the results of the two long running tasks. Both tasks have to complete (or cancel/fail) before the progress form closes and the program goes on (or closes).

So, the progress form (Form1) only contains two listboxes (ListBox1 and ListBox2) and the following code:

```
Public Delegate Sub ShowProgressDelegate(ByVal message As String)

Public Class Form1

Public Sub AddMessage1(ByVal message As String)
  If String.IsNullOrEmpty(message) Then
    Exit Sub
  End If

  If Me.InvokeRequired Then
    Me.Invoke(New ShowProgressDelegate(AddressOf Me.AddMessage1), New Object() {message})
  Else
    Me.ListBox1.Items.Add(message)
    Me.ListBox1.SelectedIndex = Me.ListBox1.Items.Count - 1
    Application.DoEvents()
  End If
End Sub

Public Sub AddMessage2(ByVal message As String)
  If String.IsNullOrEmpty(message) Then
    Exit Sub
  End If

  If Me.InvokeRequired Then
    Me.Invoke(New ShowProgressDelegate(AddressOf Me.AddMessage2), New Object() {message})
  Else
    Me.ListBox2.Items.Add(message)
    Me.ListBox2.SelectedIndex = Me.ListBox2.Items.Count - 1
    Application.DoEvents()
  End If
End Sub

End Class
```

Then I have my TestClass which simulates the long running tasks and raises progress events:

```
Imports System.Threading

Public Class TestClass

  Public Event ShowProgress(ByVal message As String)

  Private _milliSeconds As UShort

  Public Sub New(milliSeconds As UShort)
    _milliSeconds = milliSeconds
  End Sub

  Public Function Run() As UShort
    For i As Integer = 1 To 20
      RaiseEvent ShowProgress("Run " & i)
      Thread.Sleep(_milliSeconds)
    Next i

    Return _milliSeconds
  End Function

End Class
```

And finally I have my Main procedure which tries to put these two together:

```
Imports System.Threading.Tasks
Imports System.ComponentModel

Public Class Start
  Private Const MULTI_THREAD As Boolean = True

  Public Shared Sub Main()
    Dim testClass(1) As TestClass
    Dim testTask(1) As Task(Of UShort)
    Dim result(1) As UShort

    testClass(0) = New TestClass(50)
    testClass(1) = New TestClass(100)

    Using frm As Form1 = New Form1
      frm.Show()

      AddHandler testClass(0).ShowProgress, AddressOf frm.AddMessage1
      AddHandler testClass(1).ShowProgress, AddressOf frm.AddMessage2

      If MULTI_THREAD Then
        testTask(0) = Task(Of UShort).Factory.StartNew(Function() testClass(0).Run)
        testTask(1) = Task(Of UShort).Factory.StartNew(Function() testClass(1).Run)

        Task.WaitAll(testTask(0), testTask(1))

        result(0) = testTask(0).Result
        result(1) = testTask(1).Result
      Else
        result(0) = testClass(0).Run
        result(1) = testClass(1).Run
      End If

      RemoveHandler testClass(0).ShowProgress, AddressOf frm.AddMessage1
      RemoveHandler testClass(1).ShowProgress, AddressOf frm.AddMessage2

      frm.Close()
    End Using

    MessageBox.Show("Result 1: " & result(0) & "; Result 2: " & result(1))
  End Sub

End Class
```

If I set the constant MULTI_THREAD to false, everything works fine (but sequentially). But if I set if to true, it only shows the form, but no progress and it never shows the resulting message box either.
If I debug it never reaches the line after Task.WaitAll(...).

I already tried other approaches to multi threading like working with plain threads (no return values), backgroundworkers (only percentage progress, no text messages), BeginInvoke/EndInvoke on Delegates, but nothing worked or it showed the same behaviour like described above.

I was told in another forum, that Task.WaitAll blocks the UI-thread since it was called on the UI-thread, but I can't believe that since MSDN clearly states that Task.WaitAll waits for the handed-over tasks to finish or fail and I didn't hand over the UI thread.

So, I don't know what else to try, so I hope you can point out my mistake to me or to show me another way to try to solve my little problem.

Thank you very much in advance.

**Update:**
I did a little bit more testing and debugging. If I change the two "Me.Invoke(...)" in the code of my Form to "Me.BeginInvoke(...)" then I still get no progress messages shown in my form, but at least the tasks work and I get my closing message box. So the actual delivering or showing of the progress messages seems to cause the problem.

Maybe this triggers something in your minds?

Thank you again.

**Update II:**
After a lot of trial and error it seems to work, at least a little bit. Instead of the "Me.InvokeRequired" parts in the code of my form I handed over "TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext" when creating the tasks. So I at least got my progress messages shown, but the tasks still don't run completely parallel. But that's a topic for my next question here.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change Task to BackgroundWorker. This class is created for forms and have nice api to display information on form about your work.Look here for [tutorial](http://www.dotnetperls.com/backgroundworker-vbnet)

**UPDATE**
Full example, because in comments it looks ugly:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private BackgroundWorker bw = new BackgroundWorker();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        bw.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
        bw.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
        bw.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(bw_DoWork);
        bw.ProgressChanged += new ProgressChangedEventHandler(bw_ProgressChanged);
        bw.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(bw_RunWorkerCompleted);
    }

    void bw_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        if ((e.Cancelled == true))
        {
            this.tbProgress.Text = "Canceled!";
        }

        else if (!(e.Error == null))
        {
            this.tbProgress.Text = ("Error: " + e.Error.Message);
        }

        else
        {
            this.tbProgress.Text = "Done!";
        }
    }

    void bw_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.tbProgress.Text = (string)e.UserState;            
    }

    void bw_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        var worker = sender as BackgroundWorker;

        for (int i = 1; (i <= 10); i++)
        {
            if ((worker.CancellationPending == true))
            {
                e.Cancel = true;
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                // Perform a time consuming operation and report progress.
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
                worker.ReportProgress((i * 10), "status you want "+i.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Since I already stated BackgroundWorker has only percentage progress, but I can't provide that since getting the value for 100% needs the same amount of time like doing the actual work. So I need message progress to at least show the user where he's standing...

Comment: But there is a ReportProgress method look here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221403(v=vs.95).aspx

Comment: Yeah, this method you can give a number between 1 and 100 showing the share of work that is done, but you can't provide a text message.

Comment: You can pass also your own object like this: worker.ReportProgress((i * 10), "status you want "+i.ToString()); and read it like this: void bw_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.tbProgress.Text = (string)e.UserState;            
        }

Comment: OK, I will give this a try as well, but putting a BackgroundWorker into the form binds the form to only this task, and I would like my progress form to maybe work with different long running tasks.

Comment: Give info if you have problems. I hope this will help you

Comment: OK, after a bit of experimenting it seems to work with the BackgroundWorkers, although the Form is not re-usable anymore, so this wouldn't be my first choice for a solution.

Comment: Because all the work and event handling happens inside the form, so for doing a slightly different thing I need to create a copy of this form and change the code of the form accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

you process might taking much of resources available at system side.
it is just starting only new task, try starting complete new thread for heavy processes

you can even start your progress UI in separate thread so that it wont stop responding

```
Thread nThread;
private void Button1_Click(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    nThread = new Thread(ShowDlg);
    nThread.Start();
}

private void ShowDlg()
{
    Form1 nWin = new Form1();
    nWin.ShowDialog();
}
```

Comment: So you say I should start a thread which then starts my two threads?

Comment: No, start two separate thread not background worker, OR start your progress UI in new thread this will create TWO UI Threads

Answer (score 0):

You are calling WaitAll after you start the tasks, which will block the UI thread, thus your progress will not get shown.

You should specify a callback or continuation task to get executed once the tasks are complete, and do the final stuff in there, e.g. show the results and close the progress form.

```
Task.Factory.ContinueWhenAll(tasks, Sub(antecedents)
  result(0) = testTask(0).Result
  result(1) = testTask(1).Result
  RemoveHandler testClass(0).ShowProgress, AddressOf frm.AddMessage1
  RemoveHandler testClass(1).ShowProgress, AddressOf frm.AddMessage2

  frm.Close()
  MessageBox.Show("Result 1: " & result(0) & "; Result 2: " & result(1))
End Sub
```

I'm not normally a vb.net programmer, so you might have to adjust it a bit to make sure the closures work ok and you marshal some of those calls back to the ui thread

Comment: I already experimented with this Factory.ContinueWhenAll, but it didn't get better, but I will give that another try, thank you.